# NSURLSessionDataDelegate method didReceiveData and others are not called

Tags: swift, ios8.1

I am having a problem that didReceiveData and didCompleteWithError are not called. Here is my code :

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, NSURLSessionDataDelegate, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate {
.
.
.
}
```

---

```
@IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    var session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:nil)

    let postParams = "email="+"rabcd@gmail.com&password="+"abcd"

    let url = NSURL(string:"http://myurl.com/api/v1/user/login")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.HTTPBody = postParams.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)


    task.resume()


}
```

These are delegates I implemented

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {

}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {

}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {

}
```

Here I watched with break points

`didReceiveResponse` is called but other two are not getting called.

Please help !

Comment: Have you got the solution? Am also stuck up with the same scenario

Comment: you can use completion handler for this.

Answer (score 15):

Implement the completion handler in your delegate method

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition.Allow) //.Cancel,If you want to stop the download
}
```

Comment: Completion handler works good that I already know but I wanted to go with the delegate method.

Comment: To make the other delegate methods work you should call the completion handler with NSURLSessionResponseDisposition.Allow

Comment: definitely will try it :)

Comment: Expanding on this answer by providing a link to the relevant part of Apple's docs - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDataDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionDataDelegate/URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveResponse:completionHandler:

Answer (score 5):

I'll confirm ChezhianNeo's comment about calling the didRecieveResponse delegate's completionHandler with NSURLSessionResponseAllow, as shown below

```
- (void) URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:    (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition))completionHandler {

completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
}
```

This enabled the didRecieveData delegate method to be called as well.

What also works, at least it did for me, is to simply not implement the didReceiveResponse method in your delegate, but do implement the didReceiveData method - "skipping" the didReceiveResponse method allows didReceiveData method to be called, which doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense, but it works.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 2):

For others :
In my case, the delegate **didReceiveData**  was not called even after I :
 1. set the delegate in NSURLSession.
 2. implement didReceiveResponse with NSURLSessionResponseAllow

The reason :
Using dataTaskWithRequest with **completion handler** prevent calling the delegate.
you must use the dataTaskWithRequest **without** completion to use NSURLSession delegates.

Comment: And how am I going to be able to access the data and/or errors without the completion?