# URLSessionDelegate Function Not Being Called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to process data as it comes in, so I've instiated a URL session like so:

```
let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: operationQueue);
```

I also set the class to be a URLSessionDataDelegate:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, URLSessionDataDelegate{
```

Lastly, I implement the didReceive data function like this:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                dataTask: URLSessionDataTask,
                didReceive data: Data){
    print(data)
}
```

However, the function is never being called.

I run my session like this:

```
let session1 = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    print(data!);
}
```

It prints the data from the callback, but not from the delegate. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I also added the following:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                dataTask: URLSessionDataTask,
                didReceive response: URLResponse,
                completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void){
    completionHandler(URLSession.ResponseDisposition.allow);
}
```

However, the delegate method is still not being called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSURLSessionDataDelegate method didReceiveData and others are not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828593/nsurlsessiondatadelegate-method-didreceivedata-and-others-are-not-called)

Comment: Technically yes, but in this case the accepted solution offered in that question will not work in this case, as I found out the hard way beating my head on my desk for hours before finding the obvious answer.

Comment: Did you achieve to make it? @Dan

Answer (score 27):

The reason this is not working is that you're creating your data task with a completion handler. Instead you must use the `dataTask(with:)` function instead.

I also missed this in the documentation and spent hours wondering why my delegate methods weren't being called.

From the docs:

> By using the completion handler, the task bypasses calls to delegate methods for response and data delivery, and instead provides any resulting 
>   NSData, URLResponse, and NSError objects inside the completion handler. Delegate methods for handling authentication challenges, however, are still called.

Comment: How can I access the data and errors without the completion handler??

Comment: @Jalil when not using the completion handler, you need to implement the `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` method `- URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:` along with the `NSURLSessionDataDelegate ` method `- URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData:` which when used together, accomplishes the same thing. Keep in mind though that unlike with a completion handler, that you'll need to manually build up an NSData object (or a file on disk) by concatenating the data blocks provided in `didReceiveData:`.