# URLSession delegate methods don't works

Tags: ios, swift, api

I'm going to read file from API, but its size equal 1.6mb and it takes so much time. I wish to read it by parts, and when i founds data which i needs, i'm going to stop recieve data. I trying to use some delegate methods, but they don't works. I don't understand what goes wrong?
I have next code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate {

    var httpString = "hided"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getLogBinData()
    }

    func getLogBinData() {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        if let url = URL(string: httpString + "log.bin") {
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request)
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) {
        print()
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        if dataTask.countOfBytesReceived >= 500 {
            print(dataTask.countOfBytesReceived)
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    dataTask: URLSessionDataTask,
                    didReceive response: URLResponse,
                    completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
        if dataTask.countOfBytesReceived >= 500 {
            print(dataTask.countOfBytesReceived)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239757/urlsessiondelegate-function-not-being-called

Comment: @ShauketSheikh, oh my... it works, thank u. but why if one of delegate methods have handler other delegate methods don't works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according the comment, i edited code and it's worked.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate {

    var httpString = "hided"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getLogBinData()
    }

    func getLogBinData() {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        if let url = URL(string: httpString + "log.bin") {
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request)
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        if dataTask.countOfBytesReceived >= 500 {
            print(dataTask.countOfBytesReceived)
        }
    }
}
```