# URLSessionDelegate methods not called

Tags: swift, urlsession

Firstly, I already checked similar existing questions, and none of the answers apply.
[NSURLSession delegates not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694651/nsurlsession-delegates-not-called)
[URLSessionDelegate Function Not Being Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239757/urlsessiondelegate-function-not-being-called)

I am trying to download a file using `URLSessionDownloadTask`, like so

```
class MyNetworkManager : NSObject
{
    static let instance = MyNetworkManager()

    var downloadSession : URLSession?

    init()
    {
        super.init()

        let downloadConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        downloadSession = URLSession(configuration: downloadConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }

    func download(_ url : URL)
    {
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        let downloadTask = downloadSession?.downloadTask(with: urlRequest)

        downloadTask?.resume()
    }
}

extension MyNetworkManager : URLSessionDelegate
{
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64,
                    totalBytesWritten: Int64,
                    totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64)
    {
        // 
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL)
    {
        //
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    task: URLSessionTask,
                    didCompleteWithError error: Error?)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

However, no `URLSessionDelegate` methods are called.

Normally, delegate methods are not called if you create a task with completion handler - that is not the case, I'm only using `URLRequest` as parameter when creating a task.

Session's `delegate` is properly set, and after calling `downloadTask?.resume()` its `state` property is `running`

`MyNetworkManager` is a singleton, I'm using it like so

```
MyNetworkManager.instance.download(someURL)
```

so an instance is definitely retained.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Between the bad signature delegate methods, the `MyNetworkManager` instance that might be released too soon, a missing delegate method (imagine you got error and not success), etc. It's laking some infos.

Comment: @Larme That's not the case, `MyNetworkManager` instance is retained

Comment: @matt Good point. Edited the question. `MyNetworkManager` is a singleton, trying to download using `MyNetworkManager.instance.download(someURL)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must conform to the relevant protocols, e.g.:

```
extension MyNetworkManager: URLSessionDelegate {
    // this is intentionally blank

    // obviously, if you implement any delegate methods for this protocol, put them here
}

extension MyNetworkManager: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64,
                    totalBytesWritten: Int64,
                    totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        print(#function)
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        print(#function)
    }
}

extension MyNetworkManager: URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    task: URLSessionTask,
                    didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        print(#function, error ?? "No error")
    }
}
```

If you don’t conform to [`URLSessionDownloadDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondownloaddelegate), it won’t call `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` methods.